# How to include xsi attributes in the response using just wso2 dataservices

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am using only Wso2 DSS and building webservices from an oracle DB. I know we can specify the namespace in serviceNamespace attribute. We the want to include other XSI attributes in the XML response like xsi:schemaLocation="xxx.xsd". Any pointers how to go about it. We do not want to use XSLT transformation as the same response should support JSON as well.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK adding XSI attributes or attribute namespaces is not possible in current DSS versions.I have raised a Jira(https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DS-1248) to track this improvement and it will be added in future releases.

Thanks.